How do I convert a structure's data to the character data type and fill it in an array for UART transmission and reception?
I am trying to solve the following problem where I am supposed to send the data of a structure from one micro-controller to another using UART.
The problem statement is as follows:
Write a sample program to send a sequence of 10 signals of different sizes from one micro-controller to another.
An API to push the data over physical layer is provided as int SendData (char *ByteSequence) and the API to receive the data is provided as int RecvData (char *RcvdSequence)
The 10 signals would be:
a) int temp, b) double Pressure1, Pressure2, ...., Pressure7, c) unsigned char id (values 1-100), d) bool validity
This is what I think: there will be a structure which I need to convert every individual member of structure to char. Then I need to fill it all in an array and transmit it. Similarly, I will have to decode the received array and fill it in the structure.
Is my thinking correct? I have never done something like this. Please help me think more clearly.

This isn't just about UART, it does not change the problem in any way if you must encode/serialize some bunch of arbitary data into bytes, and decode/deserialize them back, whether the bytes go through UART, SPI, I2C, Ethernet, or you save them to file. Please note the API has no mechanism to tell how many bytes you will send, the length is not explicitly stated and the API lacks documentation how many bytes it will send or will it stop at some termination character like NUL or linefeed, so I think the task is poorly framed even if the intention is good. Maybe you are given assumptions.

@Justme You're right, I am given assumptions. This problem was asked in a company's interview and they really don't want to see how well you can come up with generic solution. They just care if you understand the question and come up with a solution as quick as possible. The solution may not be an ideal solution.

OK, but do you understand that without knowing all the details and assumptions will lead to a non-working solution? The company just wants to know how would you start solving this in general and have the right questions to figure out the details. The worst solution is the one you come up as fast as possible and expect it to work but it does not work because you did not  bother to check the framing of the problem, that someone else might not have even thought yet but must be taken into considerarion. So what to answer depends what the company expects, not how it should be done.

@Justme The question statement which I have mentioned in the description is all I know. How would you go on to solve the problem?

Like I said, the problem is poorly framed, and the correct or best implementation to solve it is subject to debate and further discussion, which may be intentional because it is an interview question. There might be infinite amount of correct ways to solve it and also infinite amount of incorrect ways. Without further details, the problem is unsolvable unless you make some assumptions about what kind of data and how you can send over the given API. You already assume there is a struct, and you can also define your own assumptions how you think the API works.

While not a direct answer, this may give some ideas: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/630842/sending-int16-t-or-uint32-t-data-over-serial-on-stm32f103-microcontroller

Regarding strings and UART:
char is supposedly there because this should be a byte stream and not because they expect you to send it as an ASCII string (which is an inefficient format). In that case char is a poor choice and unsigned char/uint8_t should be used instead, since the char type could be signed and is therefore a poor choice for representing raw binary data.
However, the API you are given int SendData (char *ByteSequence) with no size parameter suggests it must be a null terminated string or otherwise something with a "sentinel value" to mark the end. Well sure, we can have that function count the bytes, but it would be better if they were passed as a parameter.
It's not really OK to send null terminated strings without a carrier protocol across UART other than maybe during short distance on-board communication, but even that is questionable. Real-world UART protocols almost always look like:
<sync byte(s)> <size> <payload> <checksum>
So in a professional context you ought to cook up a protocol like that, particularly if dealing with RS-232 or RS-485 leaving the board.
Additionally, sprintf and similar functions are very inefficient and we'll like to keep those away from out MCU program whenever possible. The whole of stdio.h is to be avoided, not only for performance reasons, but also because it's such a dangerous library overall. Variadic functions in particular are notorious bug sources.

Regarding structs:
struct are problematic because of alignment/padding. If you store everything in a struct, then you might not be able to trivially serialize it byte by byte, because there could be padding bytes which 1) should not be sent and 2) may not be present on the target in case that MCU uses a different alignment or no alignment at all.
So if you use a struct, then the only 100% portable way to serialize its contents is to memcpy member by member, which in turn makes it inefficient.
However, a sensible struct layout with no padding might be possible (this is pseudo code):
  typedef struct
  {
    int32_t temp;
    double Pressure1, Pressure2, ...., Pressure7
    unsigned char id;
    bool validity;
  } stuff;  

On all mainstream systems, padding/alignment could only be a problem at the end where id and validity supposedly takes up one byte each, which on a 32 bit MCU means there will be two padding bytes in the end. Meaning we may still be able to use this struct as long as we don't send the final padding. So no iterating based on sizeof(stuff) - rather something like this:
stuff the_stuff;
for(uint8_t* data = (uint8_t*)&the_Stuff; i<offsetof(stuff,validity)+1; i++)
  send(*data);


Regarding double:
double is an oddball type which mostly belongs in the PC programming world. In embedded systems, we have the following categories of MCUs:

Low end like 8-bitter, 16-bitter or Cortex M0-M3 with no FPU what-so-ever.
Mid-range Cortex M4 that have a single precision FPU (float) but not necessarily double precision.
High end MCUs with double precision FPU.

On the low end parts, you should simply avoid floating point since it will result in very inefficient code, since the compiler will have to load in software floating point libs in your code to handle it. Same thing on mid range MCUs when you use double.
In addition, floating point may or may not be portable IEEE754. I guess some oddball DSPs and the like might use different formats.

Regarding endianness:
All data of integer or floating point type larger than 1 byte is subject to endianness. (What is CPU endianness?) Meaning that in case of raw data, you need to come up with a network endianness for your custom protocol. Then during serialization/deserialization of the structs, take this in account. Not an issue if the data is sent as strings though.

For all we know, the API is unknown and the first byte or two might define the message length for binary data transmission, or it might be intended for null-terminated text strings and it does some processing under the hood and maybe even packetizing to some line protocol.


there will be a structure which I need to convert every individual member of structure to char. Then I need to fill it all in an array and transmit it. Similarly, I will have to decode the received array and fill it in the structure. Is my thinking correct?

In principle, yes, but few more things to consider:

The transmit and receive functions accept byte arrays (or pointers to the respective memory blocks) as a parameter but what about the message length? For example, is the width of an int the same for both transmitter and receiver?
Error checks (e.g. CRC).
And maybe transmission modes as well or master/slave behaviour (i.e. if MCU-A is always going to be the sender)
and maybe something else that I can't think of at the moment.


This really sounds like a job for sprintf to create the string on one MCU and sscanf to decode the string on the other MCU.  Each value should be separated by a space (or some other unique value, like a comma). You would also need a specific delimiter (such as a newline) to indicate the end of the data.

A human readable format has some advantages but is more complicated and less efficient.

@Mattman944 Less efficient, of course.  More complicated, not in the least bit.  It is one line of code to create a string with sprintf, and one line of code to decode it with sscanf.  A full blown RPC-style implementation is far more complicated for marshalling and de-marshalling parameters.  Been there, done that.
